# Method for recursive fill the ancestor properties of item

Tags: ifc

I dont know if this question is simple or not (or silly)
You have getItem methods to get an object using its Id (expressid) .

I want to get, for example, the ancestor properties ... and calculate properties (m2, m3. etc)
I can do it recursively calling to the ifc parent elements, and then again ., and again ...

Is there any other way ? Is there any dedicated function ?

This also means to learn about the ifc itself, but I dont know if I'm reinventing the wheel ?
Thanks

PD.
Somebody with enough reputation could create a ifc.js tag ....?

Answer (score 0):

IFC.js just reflects the data within the IFC file. That means that the complexity / convolution of the data structures are not due to the library itself, but to the data structure of the IFC schema. Indeed, getting a bit familiar with the schema is a requirement to perform specific operations.

Just for your information, it's quite uncommon to compute the quantity data of elements yourself (surface, volume, etc). What the vast majority of BIM softwares do is read the explicit data of the IFC file (generally expressed as QSets).

Answer (score 0):

It could be interesting to improve the ifc.js libraby to get a structured object of all properties for a construction element by its expressid.
A construction element is a leaf element under ifcRoot in class hierarchy.